# Safe Navigation Operator (?.) not working in gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have this file `gradle/build.gradle` with content as below

```
println "project name is: ${project.name}" // gives `project name is gradle`
println "expects null: ${project?.foo?.name}" // fail to run
```

In the second line, it seems the safe navigation operator `?.` does not work as expected. Here is an error message from gradle when I simply run `gradle --stacktrace` under `gradle/`:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'foo' on root project 'gradle'.
```

So, why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safe navigation operator doesn't protect you from calling invalid properties, it just protects you if a valid property is null.

The [gradle project class](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) does not have a foo property, so you see the above behaviour.

You can [protect the code](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/groovy-goodness-check-if-method-or.html) with calls to `hasProperty`